# Bootstrap validation message is pushing down the rest of my form

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a simple form in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/McHolty/pen/ozmKxK).  The `required` validation on the `name` field works just fine.  However, I want to put a little bit of padding between the two fields and when the error message is supposed to display...fill in that gap (meaning, the fields below where the error message appears does not get pushed down).  Instead, it keeps pushing the fields down to make room for the error.  When the error is fixed, the field is pulled back up.

I want something like this:

[image]

[image]

I have tried setting the position of `.errorMessage` but this changed nothing.

```
.errorMessage{
        position: relative;
        //position: absolute;  <--I've tried this, too
    }
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: So you want that room for the error to stay even when the error is not there?

Comment: Yes.  In my real solution, the error text will be smaller so the gap won't be so big (and so odd looking when the error is not there).  I just hate how the whole form moves around simply because an error message is being shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this code pen:http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/QKoLEz

Did slight workarounds in css:

```
div.form-group{
  margin-bottom:35px
}

div.has-error{
 height:0px 
}
```